# preconfigure an empty password for mysql via debconf-set-selections

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, debian, debconf

I am setting up a bash script to automate the building of a LAMP environment.

I am using `debconf-set-selections` to set options before installing mysql, phpmyadmin, etc ...

It works mainly great. But the problem is that I *have to* set an empty password for mysql and it still asks for the password during installation even with the lines typed before :

```
echo "mysql-server-5.5  mysql-server/root_password  password" | debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server-5.5  mysql-server/root_password_again    password" | debconf-set-selections
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended approach for setting an empty password during `mysql-server`'s package installation process using `debconf-set-selections` depends on the package version in hand.

- MySQL 5.7

  Although it's possible to configure the password to be empty, the installation process will automatically enable the [authentication plugin `auth_socket`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/5.7/en/secure-deployment-configure-authentication.html) in such a case. Hence, the password-less login shall be conditioned on using `UNIX` socket based authentication (e.g. requiring the login to be made from the user account `root` on the local machine).

  - For the package provided by the [MySQL APT repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en):

    ```bash
    sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password "
    sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password "
    ```
  - For the package provided by the [Ubuntu package repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories):

    ```bash
    sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root-password password "
    sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root-password_again password "
    ```
- MySQL 5.5 and MySQL 5.6

  The solution suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860545/3903832) should work, with a minor addition that confirms the empty password:

  ```bash
  sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password \"''\""
  sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password \"''\""
  ```

### A fallback solution

If all approaches fail, it's possible to circumvent the issue and implicitly leave the password blank by preventing `debconf` from asking the user for a password altogether. Unfortunately, this applies to all questions, rather than just the password-related ones.

Here are two methods that achieve the desired result:

- Set `debconf`'s frontend to `noninteractive`:

  ```bash
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install [-y] [-q] mysql-server
  ```
- Set `debconf`'s priority level to `critical`:

  ```bash
  DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical apt-get install [-y] [-q] mysql-server
  ```

  This method is probably preferable as it permits the display of critical messages.

Comment: I forgot that I had asked this question. One year ago, I resolved it with the "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive" way and I have been happy with it since then.

Comment: "Although it's possible to configure the password to be empty, the installation process will automatically enable the authentication plugin auth_socket in such a case. " -- this is a colossal nuisance, so much I have commented out the `ALTER` from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst`  and added a divert so it doesn't get overwritten: `sudo dpkg-divert --divert /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst.packaged --rename /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst`

Answer (score 10):

Currently, **it is** possible to do this, but it's a little tricky.

You have to explicitly set quotes to mark an empty password, like this:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password \"''\""
```

Just tested on Ubuntu 15.10, works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

i think that your problem is that right before 'password' you need to add the word 'string' like this:

```
echo "mysql-server-5.5  mysql-server/root_password string password" | debconf-set-selections
```

btw this does the same thing but i think its cool:

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server-5.5  mysql-server/root_password string password"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try actually adding an empty argument

```
echo mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password "" | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password "" | debconf-set-selections
```