# Why doesn't MySQL root with a blank password work in shell scripts?

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu, unix, debconf

For many years the `debconf-set-selections` utility has been used by Debian/Ubuntu sysadmins to input a password for the MySQL root user before APT begins the actual package installation (e.g. `apt install mysql-server`).

However, if you install MySQL without this utility, the `root` user will have a blank password field in the `mysql.users` table, meaning you can `sudo mysql -u root` in the command line without entering a password.

If this works, why doesn't it work within shell scripts?

For example:

```
## this works fine in shell scripts (MySQL root user will have a blank password) ##
apt update
apt install mysql-server-8.0

## this only works when typed into the shell (not within a script) ##
mysql --user=root -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'ABC123';"
mysql --user=root -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

P.S. I'm aware of `mysql_secure_installation` wizard and manual queries (alternative), but I'm wondering why a blank password results in failure of MySQL access when used in Bash scripts, etc. It does not appear to be related to common issues like user, bind-address, protocol, host, socket, or general permissions.

Is there a solution here besides `debconf-set-selections` and janky `expect` guess-and-check?

Comment: This thread looks interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358918/preconfigure-an-empty-password-for-mysql-via-debconf-set-selections